# can't load gem in macruby

Tags: ruby, macos, macruby

I just started using MacRuby for a simple Mac Application, and I now have a problem.

For my project I use the [rmagick gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick).
I installed it as described with the command

> sudo macgem install rmagick

Everything worked well, but the problem is that if I try to load it in my AppDelegate.rb file with `require 'rmagick'`. I get an error saying that there is no such file to load.

This is strange, because I noticed that if I first build the project normally and then build the deployment target, I'm able to execute the application without any problems.

It would be really cool if there would be a way to use the gem in the development target, because otherwise I need 30 seconds after each change I made which in total is really much xD

Comment: do you have imagemagick installed and working?

Comment: yes I have, and as said in deployment everything works...

Comment: What if you `require 'rubygems'` first?

Comment: Adding `require "rubygems"` just worked fine :D I didn't even now that this require has a function... :D Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah **RMagick** can be a tricky one:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
```

is the answer. Also macruby apparently still requires the `require 'rubygems'`. But beware, the *module* you actually will be using is called `Magick`.

A short example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
image = Magick::Image.new "path/to/image.png"
```

[Here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/2.13.1/frames) you will find the **RMagick**-documentation.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I forgot the `require "rubygems"`. Somehow it seems for me that requires are case insensitive because it works with `rmagick` and `RMagick`